# Like option using cordova

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-like, cordova-plugins

I need a web and mobile application which will work on android, iphone and windows as well. 
I want to use facebook login for my apps and customer can like my page after login thats why i am using cordova to convert my web app into android app but i need to integrate facebook-like option which i didn't get in plugin.

### So i implemented this using oglike

```
$scope.facebookLike = function() {
    if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
        $http.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?access_token="+$localStorage.accessToken+"&object=https://www.facebook.com/Nxtlife-Technologies-Ltd-UK-180614345644169/?ref=br_rs");
        alert("like sucessfully done");        
    } else {               
        alert("Not signed in");
        $scope.facebookLogin();        
    }     
}
```

### Problem:

The code will not throwing any error but after success message it didin't make any changes to my page. like count is remains same.

Answer (score 0):

`og.likes` is for Open Graph objects – external URLs, outside of Faceook.

You **can not** like Facebook pages by *any other* means than the official Like button.

Comment: i checked it is the only option available to like mentioned at https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/494

Comment: can you suggest me any other solution regarding this problem.